# Multi Line JSON to Datatable

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using the following from Newtonsoft to deserialize some JSON data into a datatable (for the ultimate purpose of saving out to a spreadsheet if it matters);

```
var dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(returnData, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

While this works well enough, it has the problem that nested rows are lost. Below is example data of a similar format. In the ratings section only "Internet Movie Database" is saved, "Rotten Tomatoes" & "Metacritic" are lost in the conversion. Is there a deserialize method that would retain these? I'm willing to consider options that would split the results onto multiple rows OR concatenate the ratings section into a single field.

```
{
    "Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
    "Year": "2017",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "05 May 2017",
    "Runtime": "136 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "James Gunn",
    "Writer": "James Gunn, Dan Abnett (based on the Marvel comics by), Andy Lanning (based on the Marvel comics by), Steve Englehart (Star-Lord created by), Steve Gan (Star-Lord created by), Jim Starlin (Gamora and Drax created by), Stan Lee (Groot created by), Larry Lieber (Groot created by), Jack Kirby (Groot created by), Bill Mantlo (Rocket Raccoon created by), Keith Giffen (Rocket Raccoon created by), Steve Gerber (Howard the Duck created by), Val Mayerik (Howard the Duck created by)",
    "Actors": "Chris Pratt, Zoe Saldana, Dave Bautista, Vin Diesel",
    "Plot": "The Guardians struggle to keep together as a team while dealing with their personal family issues, notably Star-Lord's encounter with his father the ambitious celestial being Ego.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 12 wins & 42 nominations.",
    "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg2MzI1MTg3OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTU3NDA2MTI@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings": [{
            "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
            "Value": "7.7/10"
        }, {
            "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
            "Value": "84%"
        }, {
            "Source": "Metacritic",
            "Value": "67/100"
        }
    ],
    "Metascore": "67",
    "imdbRating": "7.7",
    "imdbVotes": "482,251",
    "imdbID": "tt3896198",
    "Type": "movie",
    "DVD": "22 Aug 2017",
    "BoxOffice": "$389,804,217",
    "Production": "Walt Disney Pictures",
    "Website": "https://marvel.com/guardians",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the solutions, I'm going to try these when I get home. In the meantime, perhaps to be clearer (or maybe even more complicated), I'd settle for concatenating the `Ratings` section to a single delimited string/field. What would be ideal is something like below.

[image]

Comment: You're about to fight the [Vietnam War of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/). What, exactly, do you need to show in your spreadsheet? Extract only what you need and do not try to create a general movie-to-spreadsheet tool or you will soon find yourself in a quagmire.

Comment: Also, which database engine do you use and what columns your table has?

Comment: There is a whole lot wrong with your current approach... without getting into too much detail, SQL Server (among other databases) can manipulate json that is contained in a nvarchar column - so you could just save it as a string, then use a SQL query to extract whichever parts you are after.

Answer (score 1):

The DataTable type to which you're de-serializing is unable to handle the one-to-many relationship between the movie and its ratings.

Try de-serializing to a more specific type that better suits your JSON objects.

You can use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to make a C# class out of a JSON object.

Once you have your C# type, you can de-serialize to that and get the C# equivalent of your objects.

```
var obj = (RootObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(returnData, (typeof(RootObject)));
```

or if your JSON data is an array of these objects:

```
var list = (RootObject[])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(returnData, (typeof(RootObject[])));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for you if you don't want to declare a class.

```
            var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

            string rating = Convert.ToString(dict["Ratings"]);

            var dtScore = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(rating);

            string MetacriticScore = dtScore.Rows[2]["Value"].ToString();
```

And there is another simple way

```
            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

            string MetacriticScore = Convert.ToString(jsonObj["Ratings"][2]["Value"]);
```